# CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile failedエラーについて

Tags: paypal

PayPalの[CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile failed]のエラーについて、
以下の様なエラーコードで、この原因がわかりますでしょうか。

```
CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile failed: Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-05-14T13:05:45Z [CORRELATIONID] => 48737e91e72a8 [ACK] => Failure [VERSION] => 120.0 [BUILD] => 8077598 [L_ERRORCODE0] => 11505 [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Start Date should be greater than current date [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Subscription start date should be greater than current date [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error )
```

Answer (score 1):

おそらくprofilestartdate の値が日本時間で過去の日付になってるからだと思います。

profilestartdate は日本時間の同日か未来の日付を設定すればよいようです。
この際、時間は無視されるようでprofilestartdate=""yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00""でよいようです。